# Is there a simple, consistent way to change the color scheme of Eclipse editors?

Tags: eclipse, colors

I'm going crazy trying to get all of the editors to look similarly. It looks like there's a different color editor option for each file type/code type, which means it takes FOREVER to customize the view.

Add to that: each code/file type color option seems to honor the default set in the generic options only if it feels like it (seems buggy).

I'm currently using Eclipse 3.4.1 (Ganymede).

Is there a version that is less buggy or is there a more consistent way to change the text colors?

Barring that, has anyone gotten a [Zenburn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:ZENBURN)-like color scheme in Eclipse that would be willing to share?

Comment: So, it turns out that if you're using a mac, this isn't such a big deal -- since I want a dark color scheme, all I have to do is invert the colors on the monitor by using the hotkey ctrl+cmd+alt+8. Works like a charm :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm working on an Eclipse plugin for this:

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme

It's by no means complete, but it does work quite well already.

Comment: Awesome! I will definitely look at what you've done when I get a chance.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like there isn't currently a good way of doing this because of the way Eclipse was designed: there's not a *good*, flexible, inheritable syntax highlight framework to bring consistency to everything.

While you can export & import preferences as Wijnand Warren's answer states, and that does work... kind of... actually going in and editing the preference files to make sure that you're only sharing color information is probably a huge pain in the butt, so not simple. Also, that still leaves the problem of finding *someone* who has put in the effort & time to create the syntax coloring in the first place.

Also, every time you add a new type of structured text editor (new language per year anyone?), you'll have to go back into settings & edit the highlighting for that language as well.

I have no experience developing for the Eclipse platform, but if someone with more experience would be willing to point me in the right direction (documentation, explanation of how things fit together, etc.), please let me know.

Comment: I posted a question related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603463/eclipse-codebase-is-there-a-place-that-can-intercept-all-the-coloring-data

Answer (score 2):

I've searched high and low for an answer to the same question and have all but given up. It is not easy to change the color scheme because, as you said, each language has its own options buried deep in the Configuration tree.

I've read a little about why 'themes' aren't available, and it has something to do with the complexity of Eclipse's XML storage technique. I'm sorry that I can't provide a real solid answer, but I just wanted to let you know that you're not alone in your frustrations.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for this too and after a bit of research found a workable solution.
This is based on the FDT editor for Eclipse, but I'm sure you could apply the same logic to other editors.

My blog post: [Howto create a color-scheme for FDT](http://blog.ansuz.nl/index.php/2009/01/26/howto-create-a-color-scheme-for-fdt/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Install the color theme plugin from http://eclipse-color-theme.github.com/update. It already consists of some good themes that you can use.

Then just go to menu *Window* → *Preferences* → *General* → *Appearance* → color theme to apply the themes.

You can download more themes from http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org.