# Eclipse codebase: is there a place that can intercept all the coloring data?

Tags: eclipse, color-scheme

I'm thinking of making an easy global dark background switch for Eclipse.

For example **intercept all the colors that are about to be rendered and replace them: (R,G,B) -> (255-R, 255-G, 255-B).**

**Can you suggest Eclipse source spots where it can be done?**

The current problems are

- Every language-color pair must be manually modified
- There are vertical bars that are always white

The related questions:

- [Is there a simple, consistent way to change the color scheme of eclipse editors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481035/is-there-a-simple-consistent-way-to-change-the-color-scheme-of-eclipse-editors#482828)
- [Dark colorscheme for eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120621/dark-colorscheme-for-eclipse)

Comment: That's an interesting way of asking that question... I hope there is something... or that one of the eclipse devs will help out making something like this.

Comment: The big problem is that Eclipse newsgroups are so unusable. I tried to find a suitable group (forum) to post this question but gave up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is none. I once explored making a dark color scheme for an Eclipse-based IDE we were creating for our customers. The vertical bars do stay white, and some other colors could not be changed too.

Now, I must say there is always an obscure way to do something. If you really want that, and have required Java programming skills, you could write an Equinox adaptor hook that would run byte-code instrumentation on SWT to intercept all color-related calls and proxy them through your color mapper. (Ask on SO if you need help with that.)