# Eclipse - editor colors - a healthy configuration

Tags: eclipse, ide, color-scheme

I use Eclipse for Java, Python, C(++) and so on. 
I'm accustomed to Vim and the dark color schemes. The default white background just hurts my eyes. And that's a real problem. It doesn't seem Eclipse supports any schemes? I tried [a Plugin](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/eclipsecolorer/)  but it doesn't seem to work for MacOS and Eclipse 3.3.2.

Is there any better option for some color support?

Thanks,
wishi

Comment: This question seems closely related to "[Dark colorscheme for eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120621/dark-colorscheme-for-eclipse)"...

Comment: See also: [best-background-color-for-your-editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503103/best-background-color-for-your-editor) here on SO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check [Fonts and colors in Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/accessibility/fontsandcolors.htm) for customization of Eclipse.

Answer (score 12):

There are some dark color themes available in the Eclipse Color Theme plugin:

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme

Answer (score 2):

Note: Eclipse Luna (4.4, to be released in June 2014) just introduced (May 2014) a default syntax coloring for dark theme when using the [Koneki project](http://www.eclipse.org/koneki/): see [bug 433607](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=433607), by [Simon Bernard](https://projects.eclipse.org/content/simon-bernard-committer-koneki):

[image: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=243299]

That illustrates how you can define your own syntax coloring theme and how you can  [register an extension to the dark theme](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/commit/?id=bc7c5eaf84573cd45d325f0f62f2d5009d07e6da) for recent (4.x) Eclipse.

Comment: The colour fonts for Python development is a bit off with Dark Luna.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Preferences" under the "Window" menu.

In the dialog that pops up, select General, then Appearance, then Colors and Fonts

Correction: for editor foreground / background colors, you need to go to the preferences dialog, then select Editors, then Text Editors

Answer (score 0):

You can also go to your source code, press the right mouse button, select an option under "Appearance color options:" and change the color using the "Color:" selector displayed.