# Color Themes For Eclipse Python Development

Tags: python, eclipse, themes

I am looking for Eclipse themes that are similar to the following and support Python/xhtml/css/js by default.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIAC1.png]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://pydev.blogspot.com/2009/07/creating-dark-theme-and-exporting-and.html)'s a dark theme and instructions on making it.
[And another.](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Rewrite_Metadata_Validator/SoC_2008/PyDev_integration_with_the_Darklooks_theme)

There was some discussion of this on SO [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506999/eclipse-editor-colors-a-healthy-configuration).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a whole website dedicated to color schemes in Eclipse
http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/

The color schemes on this site can be imported as an EPF preference file directly or alternatively via the Eclipse Color Theme Plugin found here:
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme

Comment: That isn't for python though

Answer (score 1):

[Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3) is built on Eclipse and includes themes. With PyDev it seems pretty good for Python development, although it is web-focused.