# How to change background of all VIEWS in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, ide, customization

I would like to get a dark look for Eclipse IDE (Aptana).
I changed background color of code editors and other colors.
But i can't figure out, how to change background color of all views ...
In Window -> Prefenreces -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts i can tweak only few views (Plugin Manager, Script view, file view) but not all.
Is there a way to do it ?
What configuration files should i edit ?

Answer (score 14):

Update July 2012 (31 months later):

With the latest Eclipse4.2 (June 2012, "Juno") release, you won't depend on the OS colors anymore and can choose precisely the colors for each view (or any other elements) of your IDE.
See the article by [Lars Vogel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548637/vogella) in "[Eclipse 4 is beautiful – Create your own Eclipse 4 theme](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2012/07/11/eclipse-4-is-beautiful-create-your-own-eclipse-4-theme/)":

[image: Eclipse fully dark theme]

> If you want to play with it, you only need to write a plug-in, create a CSS file and use the **`org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme`** extension point to point to your file.
> If you export your plug-in, place it in the “dropins” folder of your Eclipse installation and your styling is available.

---

Original answer: December 2009

As mentioned in the question [Color Themes for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96981/color-themes-for-eclipse), that kind of setting mainly concern the editor:

[image: http://web.archive.org/web/20120926185411/http://img188.i_mageshack.us/img188/1516/inkpot.png]

But for the rest of the eclipse editor, [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.pdt/msg03367.html) points out the difficulty:

> This is actually quite hard problem, because it seems that every plugin has it's own colors and you cannot any way set defaults which would inherit down to different plugins.
>
> No, what you need to do is to change colors in every plugin. I think this is a problem in Eclipse's color management in general and not a PDT's problem.

The SO answer to [Dark color scheme for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120621/dark-color-scheme-for-eclipse/1109617#1109617) mentions:

> Most of the other views are controlled by the colors specified by the operating system.
> For example, on Windows you can head to the Advanced Appearance settings and change the Window item with your desired colors.
> Of course, this means all your applications change across the entire operating system, which may be good or bad depending on your taste.

Answer (score 2):

For aptana, at least version 3, there are Themes to set colours of all the elements.

[image: Aptana theme selection]