# In Eclipse, way to change the background color of side panes (Package Explorer, Task List, Outline, etc)

Tags: eclipse

I know how to change the syntax highlighting color rules for the Text Editor pane.

Any way to do the same for other panes?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569364/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-navigator-view-in-eclipse/2569440#2569440 help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are thinking of [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/)?

Comment: LOL, yes, Eclipse, not Emacs.  Sorry -- huge think-o.