# UI color in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, colors, themes

I just added "Eclipse Color Themes" to my Eclipse UI and I am able to change text editing.

Is there a way to change the whole Eclipse UI (Project Explorer, Console, Problems, etc... )? Not just text editing window.

Comment: http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/

Answer (score 1):

With that Plugin, no.

The IDE colors for views and menus follows the standarts for your OS, as mentioned in [How do I change the background color of the Navigator view in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569364/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-navigator-view-in-eclipse)

-- EDIT 2

I've found something kinda promising, even though i haven't tested it. Check this out: http://personales.ya.com/nimrod/screenshots-en.html

-- EDIT 1

How to change Console's color scheme manually:

[image]

How to change the Tab panel color scheme manually:

[image]

Comment: I got it - many thanks! Is there plugin for this (to change the coloring of whole UI)? By hand only?

Comment: I don't think so. There are some few things you can customize, like Tab's and Console's scheme color (see the images in the update).

Comment: It seems working with JAVA but how about CDT (coloring, syntax highlighting)?

Comment: You mean the NIMROD project? Since the UI from Eclipse is Java/SWT, the plugin changes the Eclipse scheme itself... Have a look at the last screenshots from the page I shared.

Comment: Have you found the answer you looked for?

Comment: Just for the record, EOS plugin (to use Nimrod) doesn't work with Eclipse Juno anymore.

Comment: The link for edit 2 appears to be dead. Does anyone have the content stored anywhere?