# How do I change colors for the Java Docs Hover Over in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, colors

If you hover over a standard library Java method in Eclipse, you get a hover over dialog. How can you change the color of the text in that hover over dialog?

Answer (score 3):

As this [thread illustrates](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg20570.html), those colors (background and foreground) are controlled by the colors used by the OS.

See "[background color of the Common Navigator View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439007/changing-ui-color-in-eclipse/2439062#2439062)" for instance.
Or: "[How to change background of all VIEWS in Eclipse IDE ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933367/how-to-change-background-of-all-views-in-eclipse-ide/1933454#1933454)": same issue.