# How to change Eclipse project explorer background color?

Tags: eclipse, themes, eclipse-indigo

Can someone direct me to the preferences location for changing the color of the Project Explorer window in Eclipse Indigo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, from the answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866471/eclipses-package-explorer-background-color-follows-windows-theme-i-want-to-cha) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473182/ui-color-in-eclipse) question. I don't think that's possible, but you could probably play around with the ***Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts*** settings.

Comment: Please avoid down-voting the answer simply because it's not the answer you came here expecting. If you down-vote, leave a reason why or post an alternate answer.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question

Comment: Doesn't help -1

Comment: I have searched all the items inside Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts. But none of them change the background color of the project explorer. where is it?