# Change Eclipse window color

Tags: eclipse, colors, background, themes, color-scheme

I've been using Eclipse for a while now, as we need it in class to work with xml files.

I'm rather a fan of using dark backgrounds, as I find it easyer for the eyes.
I've found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120621/dark-color-scheme-for-eclipse) on how to change the theme in Eclipse, but this only changes the color scheme in the coding window.

Is there a way to change the entire color scheme for the whole program (sidebars, background color, foreground color, ...) in Eclipse like you have in Visual Studio?

offtopic: I want to do the same in NetBeans

EDIT: finally got it to work, but my color scheme s*cks.
Does anyone have a good scheme I can use or some CSS file I may import?
It would be perfect if it fits with any dark Color Theme (Monokai, NightLion Aptana Theme, Oblivion, Obsidian, Pastel, RecognEyes, Sublime Text 2, Sunburst, Wombat or zenburn). Looking at this list, I notice a lot of themes are dark. Too bad the program itself hasn't got themes (unless the Chrome Theme to change everything ourselves)

Comment: Scheme is a language.  Retagged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse 4, you can use the [Eclipse 4 Chrome Theme](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-4-chrome-theme#.UIlNHCGlwz8) to style *everything* in the program using CSS (or properties for the most used UI elements).

Comment: Can you explain me how to work with it?  
I want to be able to use some sort of 'Dark theme' like in Visual Studio where **everything** is in a dark color scheme, not only the coding window.

Answer (score 3):

Many of the colors can be adjusted via *Preferences* > *General* > *Appearance* > *Colors and Fonts*. For things that are not configurable there, they're controlled by tour operating system color settings.