# Editor look in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

[image: Screenshot of some Java code in TextMate]

How do I make my Eclipse editor look something like this? I'm kind of annoyed by the default layout:

[image]

Comment: Please see: [Dark color scheme for Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/120621/2619912)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*i hope i understood you right! The following guide schould help you putting the UI in your prefered colourscheme:*

**Manually:**

bg colour:
goto Windows>Preferences>General>Editors>Text Editors 
Browse and seleczt the Appearance color options (e.g.black)
( pay attention and uncheck the default box!)

font:
goto Windows>Preferences>General>Appearance>Colors and Fonts
Java>Java Editor> Text font--select a font from a list

text colour: 
goto Java>Editor>Syntax Colouring
select the java element of your choice and change the colour;

save your settings and there you go!

on Linux you find everything under System/Preferences/Appeareance

**AUTOMATICALLY:**
goto  http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/ and take your choice ;)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window -> Preferences.

Enter Text Editor in the search box.

In text editor you can enter you desired colors.

Additinal colors can be configured in fonts and colors preferences section